# How can I block an application/game I own on my Mac?

Tags: macos, productivity, selfcontrol

For OS X, there is [SelfControl](http://visitsteve.com/made/selfcontrol/) which can make it so you cannot go specific websites (which you specify) for certain amount of time (which you also specify). The program's great for productivity... unfortunately, if I don't go to my favorite websites, I always end up playing games, specifically Starcraft 2.

Is there any program or code to block myself from playing this game for a given amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're the admin most likely even if you find the right app you will be able to disable it too :)

I strongly suggest to excercise your will and train yourself to be able to do what you have to.
Use Starcraft as some kind of reward: "I did task 1 and 2 and now I can finally dedicate 20 minutes to my lovely Protoss..."
So play happily but set an alarm to stop you rewarded pause and get back to work / study again.
It's like a gym and it's software you "install" in your mind: always working, always with you :)

ps
Starcraft 2 is heavy drug